# Finding the cross-section

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I need to have the 3D plot of this picture below. To be precise, I need it to be the same like the blue one. However, i dont know how figure it out. Can you help me?

```
ContourPlot3D[
  {1 - y - z == 0, y - Sqrt[x ] == 0, z == 0}, 
  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: What does this have to do with "find the cross-section"?

Comment: Full comment didn't paste: without the niceties... `RegionPlot3D[
 z <= 1 - y && y >= x^(1/2) , {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> Mauve, Lighting -> False, 
 Mesh -> False, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]`

Answer (score 3):

Use `RegionPlot3D`:

```
Clear[x, y, z]
RegionPlot3D[{x < 1 && y < 1 && z < 1 && z < 1 - y && y > (x)^(1/2)},
 {x, 0, 1.1}, {y, 0, 1.3}, {z, 0, 1.1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.4]}, Mesh -> None, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: thanks for your help :D